# Image with float property not in line with elements (css)

Tags: html, css

I have two tables and one image and I want them to be in one line while using the float attribute.
How can I prevent the image and the right table to jump below the other elements when making the browser window smaller?

[before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PPD0m.jpg)

[after](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cFhm8.jpg)

```
    <body>
    <div>

    <table class="datagrid">
        <tr>
            <th colspan="2">Test table one</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="label">Test 1:</td>
            <td class="value">Text 1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="label">Test 2:</td>
            <td class="value">Text 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="label">Test 3:</td>
            <td class="value">Text 3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="label">Test 4:</td>
            <td class="value">Text 4</td>
        </tr>        
    </table>

    <table class="datagrid">
        <tr>
            <th colspan="2">Test table two</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="label">Test 1:</td>
            <td class="value">Text 1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="label">Test 2:</td>
            <td class="value">Text 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="label">Test 3:</td>
            <td class="value">Text 3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="label">Test 4:</td>
            <td class="value">Text 4</td>
        </tr>        
    </table>

        <img style="float: left; height: 200px;" src="data:image/png;base64,..."/>
</div>
</body>

table.datagrid tr th
{
text-align: left;
padding: 5px 5px;
background: #ebebeb;
}

table.datagrid
{
float: left;
width: 30%;
margin-right: 15px;
}
```

Comment: If those three elements don't fit on a single line, then they simply don't fit. I.e. what do you expect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a responsive layout and set the width of each block to, say, 33%, leaving some room (1%) for the margines. 
First of all, I would wrap the image in a div wrapper

```
<div class="imagery"><img src=""/></div>
```

Style the image wrapper

```
.imagery {
float: left;
width: 33%;}
```

And make sure the image scales appropriately:

```
.imagery img {
max-width: 100%;
height: auto;
display: block;
```

}

Then I would set the tables width to 33% and 1% for the margines

```
.datagrid {
float: left;
width: 33%;
margin-right: 0.5%;}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ny86yjm4/

Answer (score 0):

First of all, name your <div> after your <body>. Then, set a min-width rule to that div.

Then, you just set the 2 tables and the image to float to the left.
Let's call your div 'content' for brevity. You also have to give an id to your img element, we'll call this x-img.

HTML:

```
<body>
<div id="content">
...

<img id="x-img" ... >
</div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
div#content{
   min-width: 50em; /* Or whichever, this value is going to be trial and error, you can also use px */
}

table.datagrid, img#x-img{
   display: inline;
   float: left;
   clear: none;
}
```

Otherwise, you can mess with other values; CSS is a lot of trial and error.